# Problems using LWP::Protocol:https under macOS Catalina

Tags: macos, perl, https, lwp

When I run a program using `LWP::UserAgent` (that worked until now) I get the error
message

```
501 Protocol scheme 'https' is not supported (LWP::Protocol::https not installed)
```

But when I run `cpan` it says `LWP::Protocol::https` is installed:

```
cpan[1]> install LWP::Protocol::https                                                                                    
Reading '/Users/yannis/.cpan/Metadata'
  Database was generated on Sun, 27 Sep 2020 12:56:00 GMT
LWP::Protocol::https is up to date (6.09).
```

What can I possibly be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by installing `Net::SSLeay` and `IO::Socket::SSL`.

A pity `LWP::Protocol::https` cannot emit a warning asking the user to install those two…

Comment: *"A pity LWP::Protocol::https cannot emit a warning asking the user to install those two…"* - These are installed automatically as dependency if you install LWP::Protocol::https via cpan. So the problem is not that LWP does not complain at runtime but that you somehow had a messed up installation.

Comment: I installed LWP::Protocol::https by cpan using the standard cpan install command. How could I mess something up?

Comment: The [Makefile.PL](https://metacpan.org/source/OALDERS/LWP-Protocol-https-6.09/Makefile.PL) clearly lists IO::Socket::SSL as dependency and this one has Net::SSLeay as dependency. Net::SSLeay needs openssl and a compiler installed though, so if this is not available the installation fails. If one in this case simply forces the installation anyway it results in a messed up incomplete installation. I'm not saying that it was this way, but it might.

Comment: Re "*A pity LWP::Protocol::https cannot emit a warning asking the user to install those two…*", eh... LWP::Protocol::https won't install without these. I think these are warning enough! Did you ignore the test failures and force the install? That's on you!